# What is the best way to rearrange files in a big project in Intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

I am new to IntelliJ IDE so i might ask silly question.

I am using IntelliJ IDE and working on a big project. I want to change the name of 1 directory(A to B) and want to move few files of this directory in to another directory(C), what is the best way of doing it so that I don't need to change the package name inside .java file(i.e IDE handle all those things)?

Comment: Right click > Refactor > Move and Right click > Refactor > Rename

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen that's correct for renaming now how to move files from this directory to different directory?

Comment: Like I said in the first half of my comment: Right click > Refactor > Move. Just dragging & dropping might work as well

Comment: IntelliJ is well named - it's very smart, indeed.  After a while you'll feel like it's reading your mind as you develop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the directory in the project explorer ->refactor->rename A to B.

Then drag and drop the files you want to move into the C package using the project explorer.

Intellij will automatically change the package definitions at the top of the .java files for you.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Or use `shift+F6` for renaming directory.

For moving files between directories 
Just select file (If you want to move multiple file , select files by pressing `ctrl + select`) and move to destination directory